# Building libusb on Ubuntu with android-ndk

Tags: android-ndk, libusb

I am trying to build libusb with android ndk on Ubuntu 12.10.

I type in the ndk-build command and it fails on compiling io.c with the following error.

```
jni/libusb/io.c:34:25: fatal error: sys/timerfd.h: No such file or directory
```

Where can I get timerfd.h? Isn't it supposed to come with Linux kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function that you are searching has nothing to do with the "Linux-kernel"!
This funktion belongs to the C-language.

On Android devices the clib is crippled ( sorry: stripped ) down to the minimum
 and is called bionic.

Check the net for more infos on that toppic

Good luck
Martin